# Calculate residual standard deviation from standard deviation and confidence intervals

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Suppose that, for a certain population of animals, we can predict log weight from log height as follows:

• An animal that is 50 centimeters tall is predicted to weigh 10 kg.

• Every increase of 1% in height corresponds to a predicted increase of 2% in weight.

• The weights of approximately 95% of the animals fall within a factor of 1.1 of predicted values.

QUESTION: How do I calculate residual the standard deviation of the regression? I have calculated the regression to be $log(weigh) = -5.5 + 2*log(height)$

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using natural logarithms

If your model is $$\log_e(weight) = -5.5 + 2\log_e(height) + \epsilon$$ where $\epsilon$ is is the error then this is equivalent to  $$weight = \frac1{250} \,height^2 \times e^\epsilon$$

You seem to have been told that $e^\epsilon$ is between $\frac1{1.1}$ and $1.1$ $95\%$ of the time so $\epsilon$ is between $-0.0953$ and $+0.0953$ $95\%$ of the time.

If you assume a normal distribution for $\epsilon$ with mean $0$, then $95\%$ would be the probability of being within about $1.96$ standard deviations of the mean, so this suggests a standard deviation for $\epsilon$ of about $0.0486$ which you might want to round and this may be the desired answer